# Does KNeighborsClassifier compare lists with different sizes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, scikit-learn, knn

I have to use Scikit Lean's KNeighborsClassifier to compare time series using an user defined function in Python.

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1,weights='distance',metric='pyfunc',func=dtw_dist)
```

The problem is that KNeighborsClassifier doens't seem to support my training data. They are time series, so they are lists with different sizes. KNeighborsClassifier gives me this error message when I try to use `fit` method (`knn.fit(X,Y)`):

```
ValueError: data type not understood
```

It seems KNeighborsClassifier only supports same size training sets (only time series with same lenght would be accepted, but that is not my case), but my teacher told me to use KNeighborsClassifier. So I don't know what to do...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you write an example with random data that fails, which one can copy and paste? Your question is not clear enough otherwise. What do you mean by "same size training set"? Each sample is a time series of different length? This is very prone to go wrong, but since I don't know the internals of knn there is a chance that a custom distance function may be able to recover the situation.

Comment: @eickenberg an example could be the one that user41047 when he told me to use NaNs. Yes, my time series have different lengths from each other. The problem is that I am already using a custom distance function (dtw_dist). This function supports different lengths lists, but KNN does not work even with it.

Comment: I was thinking more of an example that is copy+pasteable, contains fake data, as in @user41047's answer, and a fake distance function (or your real `dtw_dist`), and which fails giving the same error message you receive.

Comment: @eickenberg No matter if I use a standard function or my dtw_dist. I'll get this error message if I use @user41047 example or any other example which lists have different lenghts. Everything will work fine if I use something like `series = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]` or `series = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]`. I hope this time I made myself clear.

Comment: I understand the idea of your problem. If you provided a self-contained block of code that breaks, then on average probably more people will feel inclined to give it a shot and maybe come up with something interesting towards a solution of your problem. As it is now it looks like the answer combined with the comments under it look like a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two (or one...) options as far as I can tell:

1. Precompute the distances (not directly supported by `KNeighborsClassifier` it seems, other clustering algorithms do, e.g., [Spectral Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering)).
2. Convert your data to be square using `NaN`s, and handling these accordingly in your custom distance function.

## 'Square' your data using `NaN`s

So, option 2 it is.
Say we have the following data, where every row represents a time series:

```
import numpy as np

series = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3],
    [1],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
]
```

We simply make the data square by adding nans:

```
def make_square(jagged):
    # Careful: this mutates the series list of list
    max_cols = max(map(len, jagged))
    for row in jagged:
        row.extend([None] * (max_cols - len(row)))
    return np.array(jagged, dtype=np.float)


make_square(series)
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.]])
```

Now the data 'fits' into the algorithm. You just have to adapt your distance function to account for the `NaN`s.

## Precompute and use a cache function

Oh we can probably do option 1 too (assuming you have `N` time series):

1. Precompute the distances into a `(N, N)` distance matrix `D`
2. Create a `(N, 1)` matrix that is just a range between `[0, N)` (i.e., the index of the series in the distance matrix)
3. Create a distance function `wrapper`
4. Use this `wrapper` as the distance function.

`wrapper` function:

```
def wrapper(row1, row2):
    # might have to fiddle a bit here, but i think this retrieves the indices.
    i1, i2 = row1[0], row2[0]
    return D[i1, i2]
```

Ok I hope its clear.

### Complete example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
'''
'''
from mlpy import dtw_std # I dont know if you are using this one: it doesnt matter.
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np

# Example data
series = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3],

    [1],

    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
]

# I dont know.. these seemed to make sense to me!
y = np.array([
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,

    1,

    2,
    2,
    2
])

# Compute the distance matrix
N = len(series)
D = np.zeros((N, N))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        D[i, j] = dtw_std(series[i], series[j])
        D[j, i] = D[i, j]

print D

# Create the fake data matrix: just the indices of the timeseries
X = np.arange(N).reshape((N, 1))


# Create the wrapper function that returns the correct distance
def wrapper(row1, row2):
    # cast to int to prevent warnings: sklearn converts our integer indices to floats.
    i1, i2 = int(row1[0]), int(row2[0])
    return D[i1, i2]

# Only the ball_tree algorith seems to accept a custom function
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(weights='distance', algorithm='ball_tree', metric='pyfunc', func=wrapper)
knn.fit(X, y)
print knn.kneighbors(X[0])
# (array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  6.]]), array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]]))
print knn.kneighbors(X[0])
# (array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  6.]]), array([[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]]))

print knn.predict(X)
# [0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2]
```

Comment: Filling with NaNs is a *very* bad idea since most scikit-learn estimators choke on them.

Comment: (That said, padding with a magic value is the right way to go. -1 might be an option.)

Comment: @user41047 when you told me to precompute and use a cache function, were you trying to say that I should change "weights" or "metrics" paramether? I already use a custom function when I say I set "metrics" to "pyfunc" and "function" to "dtw_dist". dtw_dist supports lists with different lenghts, but KNeighborsClassifier gives the same error anyway...

Comment: @larsmans I'll try to use -1 as a magic value. Let's see if it works.

Comment: You should use `dtw_dist` to create the `(N, N)` distance matrix `D`. Then you create another matrix `(N, 1)` containing only index values. This new matrix is now your `X` for the fit method. The distance function passed to `KNN` should be the provided `wrapper` instead of `dtw_dist`. Using `-1` as magic value is probably easier.

Comment: This matrix (N,1) would be Y (the list with the classes of each series) in the fit method? I did not understand what should I give as paramether for the `predict` method if I use this implementation? Should I give the time series I want KNN to predict?

Comment: I have added example code. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @user41047 thanks for the code. It helped me to understand your point. But there's one last thing: I still did not understand what to give as paramether for `predict`. For example, I want KNN to predict the label for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], which is not part of the training set. If I run `print knn.predict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, I get `ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension`. Which kind of transformation I have to do with [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in order to predict its label?

Comment: The predictor takes input of the same form as during training: a matrix of indices. So you concatenate your test and train values (`Ntrain + Ntest = N`), and compute the distance matrix like before. You train on the first `Ntrain` examples: `knn.fit(X[:Ntrain,:], y)`, and then predict your test examples: `knn.predict(X[Ntrain:,:)`. If you do not know your test set beforehand you need a different solution.